# Simple Exercises that can help with dyslexia

Tags: dyslexia-dyslexic

I have a colleague whom I am helping to learn English and we have just discovered he has dyslexia. He really needs his degree in English and is struggling. There are simple techniques that might help him get by. Does anyone have experience with this subject? I don't need the advice to be necessarily professional.

My friend was diagnosed with ***mild dyslexia*** by a test done by a teacher. He will get the papers from professionals soon. I would be grateful if people shared some tips that can help him ***manage*** in daily life. Intuitively I was thinking of ***breaking words in syllables or smaller words*** or such exercises that can help him read better. ***I am definitely not looking to replace professional assessment***. He just has this exam soon...

I hope that there are people who have more experience with this than me. The best would be, of course, those who personally deal with this in their own life and found ways to help themselves or people they know.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't personal medical advice. I would suggest to see a licensed speech therapist to professionally guide your friend. Dyslexia is usually diagnosed by an educational psychologist. An ophthalmologist, audiologist and neurologist should be able to exclude other possible causes that cause dyslexia-like symptoms.

Generally speaking, as far as I know, style types can improve reading in dyslectic people. Such as changing the font type and size and changing the text and background color. See for example this article from the British Dyslexia Association: https://www.bdadyslexia.org.uk/advice/employers/creating-a-dyslexia-friendly-workplace/dyslexia-friendly-style-guide. There are even two fonts specifically developed for people with dyslexia:

- https://www.dyslexiefont.com/
- https://opendyslexic.org/

These fonts scored quite well according to this article: https://www.dyslexicadvantage.org/the-best-fonts-for-dyslexia/. *I'm not sure how this "study" was performed.*

[image: graph]

Colour Coded Language (CCL) also is a method often used as far as I know for dyslexic children. See for example this article: https://yoohoo.org.uk/blogs/news/how-colour-coded-language-can-support-your-dyslexic-child.

*Regarding education I know that in The Netherlands most children that are officially diagnosed with dyslexia get (30 minutes) extra time during all (not just language) exams.*

Comment: My friend is an adult and comes from a background not very aware of dyslexia. He just discovered it. And yes, he was offered an extra time of 10 minutes for this IELTS exam, but it seems so little! Thanks for the information!